# aurelia-validation detaches custom elements

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I am trying to use `aurelia-validation` for client-side validation. Though the client-side validation works quite well, it forces reevaluation of the custom elements in the view. For example, a typical flow is as follows (the order in which the custom-elements are `detached`/"`unbind`ed" may differ from time to time):

```
validation starting
custom-element#1 detached
custom-element#2 detached
custom-element#3 detached
custom-element#2 unbind
custom-element#3 unbind
custom-element#1 unbind
validation ended
custom-element#1 bind 
custom-element#2 bind
custom-element#1 attached
....
```

Naturally, re-activating the custom elements means also getting the data from the server which are needed in-order to render the elements in a meaningful way (for example, options in a dropdown, or items in a list, and so on).

Some more detail about the application: The validation rules are defined on server side (WebAPI), and an endpoint can deliver the rules for a "Entity" type. These rules are then translated to `aurelia-validation` rules on client-side. And then it is simple matter of using those rules with my target entity object (which can be of any "Entity" type, depending on the scenario; naturally rules are fetched accordingly). The example code looks like below:

```
this.clientRules = this.ruleAdapter.toAureliaRules(validationRules);
this.validationController.addObject(this.targetEntity, this.clientRules);

// and finally invoke validate when required
this.validationController.validate()
```

Please note that `targetEntity` is being used by the custom elements as well.

I am not sure how to isolate the problem and look for the root cause. Any suggestion would really nice.

**Update:** Thinking the `targetEntity` is being modified during `validate`, I also tried with following code:

```
const dummyEntity = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.entity));
this.validationController.validate({ object: dummyEntity, rules: this.clientRules });
// naturally, while trying this code I removed the addObject call
```

However, this too didn't work :(

**Update on 12.01.2018:** Interested users can also folllow the discussion over [here](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/aurelia-validation-detaches-custom-elements/629/3).

**Additional findings:** Sharing another finding if it helps. During debugging it seemed that the custom elements were detached even before starting the validation, that is before the control reaches [this line](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/validation-controller.ts#L217). Then is it possible that the root cause lies elsewhere?

**Solution:** Sorry. My bad :P  it has indeed nothing to do with aurelia-validation. The solution was to change a `if.bind` to `show.bind` :D

Comment: If you had shared a minimal viable example this problem could have been solved faster. So even if your code is private, try to add some example code, just simple divs showing the HTML structure, and some dummy validation rules.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne if that would have been possible, I would have done that. Wouldn't I? Moreover, I have posted the the parts, which seemed relevant to me for this problem.